# JMeter - Beanshell PostProcessor - Writing JSON Response Data to csv in single column

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

I am writing Result along with Response data to a csv file using BeanShell Postprocessor. Everything is working fine except following issue:
- My response data is in JSON format and while writing to csv it is being written into different columns due to presence of comma "," in json, but I have to write the whole RESPONSE DATA in single column

This is how my code looks:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

Result = "FAIL";
Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
if (Response.contains("{\"status\":true"))
       Result = "PASS";

f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Administrator/APIFramework/bean.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f);
p.println( vars.get("id") + "," + Result + "," + Response);
p.close();
f.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the commas and double quote. I checked and it worked:

```
row ="\"";
cell_value = vars.get("id");

row = row +cell_value;
row= row +"\"";

row = row + "," + Result + "," + Response;
p.println(row);
p.close();
f.close();
```

Comment: Still getting the same result :(

Comment: Still not able to find the solution, so I have used .tsv format as workaround as it serves my purpose.